# How to correct a simple function: getting error replacement has length zero

Tags: r, function

I am trying to simulate a branding process with a negative binomial offspring distribution. When I run a single branching process, the code works fine. When I wrap it in a function and use the "replicate" function to simulate many branching processes, it produces the error: "replacement has length zero"

I am a SAS convert so relatively new to R functions and looking for help! Hopefully this is a simple fix, and any advice for improvement is always welcome. Thank you in advance!

```
#######
#Single NB Branching Process with 20 generations
n<-20 #20 generations
r0<-0.9 
k<-0.25

#initialize list of population size at generation n
Z<-1
#Initiate with one index case generation 0
Z[0] <- 1
#Cluster size a generation 1
Z[1] <- rnbinom(Z[0], k,r0)
for (i in 2:n)
{
  if(Z[i-1]==0) {Z[i]=0} else 
  {
    x<-rnbinom(Z[i-1], k,r0) 
    Z[i]<- sum(x)
  }
}
print(Z)

######################
#Wrap in a function and replicate 300 times
nbbp<-function(n, r0, k)
{
  #initialize list of population size at generation n
  Z<-1
  #Initiate with one index case generation 0
  Z[0] <- 1
  #Cluster size a generation 1
  Z[1] <- rnbinom(Z[0], k,r0)
  for (i in 2:N)
  {
    if(Z[i-1]==0) {Z[i]=0} else 
    {
      x<-rnbinom(Z[i-1], k,r0) 
      Z[i]<- sum(x)
    }
  }
}
ds<-replicate(100,nbbp(20,0.9,0.25))
#Returns: Error in Z[1] <- rnbinom(Z[0], k, r0) : replacement has length zero
```

Comment: How do you want it to work with `k` non positive integer? `size = k` is the target number of trials. See the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) or the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: Arrays in R are indexed starting with 1, not 0. There is no `Z[0]` element. I get the error in both versions of your code on the `rnbinom(Z[0], k,r0)` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below does what the question asks for and is simpler.

```
nbbp <- function(n, r0, k){
  # initialize return vector
  Z <- integer(n)
  #Initiate with 1 index case generation 1
  Z[1] <- 1
  for (i in seq_len(n)[-1]){
    # No need to check the case Z[i - 1] == 0,
    #   all cases are initialized to 0 and
    #   this one hasn't changed yet
    if(Z[i - 1] > 0) {
      x <- rnbinom(Z[i - 1], k, r0) 
      Z[i] <- sum(x)
    }
  }
  Z
}

set.seed(1234)
ds <- replicate(10, nbbp(20, 0.9, 10))
ds
```

Answer (score 0):

In your standalone code, you have

```r
for (i in 2:n)
```

while in the function you have

```r
for (i in 2:N)
```

(note the capital N). I imagine that `N` is defined as something in your workspace, but not what you want. If you change that to `n`, does it work?

Comment: While this maybe a problem, this is not the cause of the error message. It never even gets to that line.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for pointing this out. I'm going to leave this here for now because it will help the OP with another problem in their function, but I recognize it does not answer the question.

Comment: Thank you both - yes in the original code I has all of the n's represented as "N" and this was a mistake (I copied an older version of the code). Good point though and thank you!